# how to search a prolog knowledge base using pyswip

Tags: python, python-3.x, search, prolog

I want to use voice commands to search my prolog knowledgebase, im using pyswip and it works but I have to write an if statement for every possible query, I have a huge knowledgebase with more than a 100 lines and if I do it this way I would have to write over 100 if statements. What I want to know is if there's a better way. For example I can write a function that is voice activated and it just puts the the query to be searched and say what the search returns

i mean if i have to write this for all events then there's no point in using pyswip:

```
if "son" in commands:
    test12 = list(prolog.query("father(michael, B)"))
    print(test12)
elif "daugher" in commands:
    test12 = list(prolog.query("father(dory, B)"))
    print(test12)
```

---

now i have tried something like this:

```
def prolog_search(A, B):
    value1 = '('
    value2 = ', '
    value3 = 'X'
    value4 = ')\"'
    value5 = '\"'
    tot_value = value5 + A + value1 + B + value2 + value3 + value4
    tot_value = str(tot_value)
    print(tot_value)
    # tot_value would be "asd(sa, B)"
    test12 = list(prolog.query(tot_value))
    #test12 = list(prolog.query())
    print(test12)

prolog_search("asd", "sa")
```

---

the theory is to later replace the "asd and "sa" with actual voice but for now i cant get it to run

after running this i get this error:

```
raise PrologError("".join(["Caused by: '", query, "'. ", pyswip.prolog.PrologError: Caused by: '"asd(sa, X)"'. Returned: 'error(type_error(callable, b'asd(sa, X)'), context(/(pyrun, 2), Variable(74)))'.
```

---

any advice?

Answer (score 0):

Forgot to add

```
prolog.consult("knowledgebase.pl")
```

At the beginning